# HBase Mapreduce Dependency Issue when using TableMapper

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am using CDH5.3 and I am trying to write a mapreduce program to scan a table and do some proccessing. I have created a mapper which extends `TableMapper` and below is my code.

```
public class TestTableMapper extends TableMapper  {

@Override
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    super.setup(context);
}

@Override
protected void map(Object key, Object value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    //do something here

}

@Override
protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    super.cleanup(context);
}
}


public class Driver extends Configured implements Tool {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new Driver(), args);
        if (exitCode==0){
            System.exit(exitCode);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf(), args[0]);
    job.setJarByClass(Driver.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob("TestTable",new Scan(), TestTableMapper.class, Text.class, TextInputFormat.class, job);
    TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars(job);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    job.waitForCompletion(true);
    return 0;
}
}
```

When I run the packaged jar, I get the below exception.

```
 15/12/16 18:15:37 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area file:/data/hadoop/mapred/staging/hduser1308282625/.staging/job_local1308282625_0001
15/12/16 18:15:37 WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hduser (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://hadoopHost:9000/home/hduser/applciations/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.3.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://hadoopHost:9000/home/hduser/applciations/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.3.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1085)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1085)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:267)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:481)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1292)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1292)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1313)
    at com.ugam.test.Driver.run(Driver.java:47)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at com.ugam.test.Driver.main(Driver.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

The netty jar is present in the hadoop shared library but I am not sure why it is searching in hdfs path.

If I use a normal Mapper without `TableMapper`, every thing runs fine, even If I use netty related stuff in my mapper.

Comment: can you please tell which command you tried to run this jar file ?

Comment: hadoop jar jarName mainclassName inputPath outputPath

Comment: please tell the actual command you executed. (with jar name, mainclass,  inputpath, outputpath)